# Closure-compile does not work on a set of files

Tags: bash, google-closure-compiler

In my server, `java -jar closure-compile/closure-compiler-v20171203.jar --js file.js --js_output_file file-compiled.js` does work.

I have the following `mini.sh` in the server:

```
for f in /opt/myapp/public/javascripts/*.js; do short=${f%.js}; java -jar closure-compile/closure-compiler-v20171203.jar --js $f --js_output_file $f; done
```

Then, when I run `./mini.sh`, it took 5 minutes to run `closure-compiler` and generated some warnings. However, when I double check the files, they still stay the same and unminified.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not allow the output file to be the same as the input file.